# Calculating the totals of odd and even numbers from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
def main():

    infile = open('numbers.txt','r')

    evenTotal = 0
    oddTotal = 0

    line = infile.readline()

    while line != '':
        total += int(line)
        line = infile.readline()

    print('The total for the even numbers is',evenTotal)
    print('The total for the odd numbers is',oddTotal)

    infile.close()
    print('All done!')

main()
```

I trying to make it so that the program reads the numbers from a file in its directory and then separates, calculates and displays the total of the two sets. The thing I am having trouble with is the part in the middle with the identification of the odds and the evens. I do know that the while loop I have written in the middle calculates the total but I don't know how to modify it to make it so it does what I want it to do.

Comment: so your question is "How do I recognize an odd number?"

Comment: You could put a check in the while loop, if int(line) % 2 == 0  (even)  then increase evenTotal by int(line) - else increase oddTotal by int(line)

Comment: is the file just a vector with numbers?

Comment: @ITellMyselfSecrets It's a file that was generated from a previous program in which there are 10 random numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: @njzk2 No it's actually "Calculating the totals of odd and even numbers from a file in Python?". I don't know how I could've made it clearer.

Comment: but you already have everything except putting the right number in the right total, so I don't understand what is blocking you.

Comment: (and you did write `I am having trouble [...] with the identification of the odds and the evens`)

Comment: Are you trying to "calculate the sum of the even numbers from a file" or to "calculate the sum of the numbers from the even-numbered lines" of the file? Your current problem description is a bit ambiguous on that...

Comment: @twalberg I'm trying to calculate the sum of the even numbers and odd numbers from a file. Sorry if that confused anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check if a number is odd or even, you should use the modulus operator.

if an integer is evenly divisible by 2, it will be even, otherwise, it is odd.
So...

```
while line != '':
    if int(line) % 2 == 0:
         evenTotal += int(line)
    else
        oddTotal += int(line)
    line = infile.readline()
```

Comment: When I added your code into the program, it gives me the error saying "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' for the if loop.

Comment: @SarahHyland Have you tried moving the code around? I don't have a file to test; if I did, I would run the program on my own (to ensure that it works). Essentially, as long as you get the idea of how to use modulus to test for evens and odds, you should be able to modify the code I wrote to get it to work.

Comment: @SarahHyland try putting the conditional statements before `line = infile.readline()`

Comment: @Freddie_V4 Alternatively, a logical AND with 1 will yield 1 if a number is odd, and typically will be faster than the MOD operator. Although whether that matters at all depends on whether we're considering 10 inputs or 10 billion...

Comment: @twalberg think you mean BITWISE AND there... :p

Answer (score 2):

from itertools you can use the partition recipe to partition into even and odd and return the sum of those

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse,imap,ifilter,tee
def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return ifilterfalse(pred, t1), ifilter(pred, t2)

def is_odd(x):
    return bool(x%2)

list_of_ints = imap(int,filter(lambda x:x.strip().isdigit(),infile))
odds, evens= partition(is_odd,list_of_ints)
print sum(evens),sum(odds)
```

it will likely be a little bit slower than freddies answer ...
but it is a good pattern to know

or as @JonClements [pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21653318#21653318) in chat

```
r = range(11)
d = dict.fromkeys([0, 1], 0)
for i in r: d[i % 2] += i
```

is a neat way to do it

Answer (score 1):

use this for even number

```py
def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for x in range(2,maximum+1,2):
        return_string += str(x) + " "
    return return_string.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# With this program in Python you will check a document for even and odd numbers and
# also it skips any text 
# It also writes 2 extra files Oddfile and Evenfile
import re

fhand = open('numbers.txt')  # file with numbers odd/even or even filled with text
text = fhand.read()
y = re.findall('[0-9]+', text)
sumeven = 0
sumodd = 0
Even = []
Odd = []
Oddfile=open('Oddfile.txt','w')
Evenfile=open('Evenfile.txt','w')
for number in y:
    if (int(number) % 2) == 0:# Checks if the number is even
        sumeven = sumeven + int(number)
        Even.append(int(number))
        Evenfile.write(str(number) + '\n')
    if (int(number) % 2) == 1:# Checks if the number is odd
        sumodd = sumodd + int(number)
        Odd.append(int(number))
        Oddfile.write(str(number) + '\n')

print("Even List is : ", Even)
print("Odd List is : ", Odd)
```

Comment: I updated my answer a little bit. The program also saves the odd and even numbers in a file...If you have a suggestion please let me know.

Comment: you somehow managed to post your answer twice. Please, review your posts and remove one of the answers.

Comment: I have posted twice but the last one is an updated version. In the last version the program also creates two files.

Comment: You should edit your own answer then and should not just post another answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have deleted the first answer